# Finding a specific coordinate in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT: I changed the procedure, and now am using application. worksheet function with vlookup and hlookup functions to find the coordinates. In theory this should give me the values I want, but I keep getting the object out of range error in my lookups.

**Scenario:** I am trying to use to inputs from a for loop to select a cell.

**Objective:** The loop retrieves an identifier and a date from worksheet 1, and uses the month/year of the date and the identifier to find a value in worksheet 2.

**Data example:**
WS2:

```
               ident1    ident2    ident3    ident4    ident5
20/01/2010      aa        az         zc        bc        ht
20/02/2010      er        da         ea        cr        hd
20/03/2010      ok        ju         nh        lo        gk
20/04/2010      uj        hg         gj        eg        nh
20/05/2010      ug        cd         ad        ea        ga
```

From my loop I get 2 values, ex: ident3 and 15/04/2010. First I want to find where that month and year are on the list for that identifier. in this case it would be "gj".

**Problem:** Here I run into 2 problems, first is being able to account for only month and year, for the date. If I wanted to find only the month, it would be straightforward with the MONTH() function, but since i have also to account for the year, i am at lost (I also tried accounting for the whole date, but since the days don't match, I couldn't bypass). How can this be done?
Second, I am using a selection for the first row, followed by a find and replace procedure for each of the identifiers, which I cannot use to get the coordinated. What is the correct way to do this?

**Code so far:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindData()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lrow As Integer, a_number As Integer 
Dim date_number As Date, LMonth As Date


For lrow = 2 To wb.Sheets("CAs").UsedRange.Rows.count

    a_number = Range("B" & lRow).Value
    date_number = Range("C" & lRow).Value
    LMonth = Month(date_number)

wb.Sheets("AMT").Cells(a_number,date_number).Value
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastCol = wb.Sheets("AMT").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastColLetter = Col_Letter(lastRow)


datefinalmatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wb.Sheets("CAs").Range("C"&lrow), _
     "AMT!$A$2:§"&lastColLetter&"$"&lastRow&","&"lastCol&",TRUE)" + 1
isinfinalmatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(wb.Sheets("CAs").Range("B"&lrow), _
     "AMT!$B$1:§"lastColLetter"$"&lastRow&","&"lastRow&",False)"


Next lrow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will accept your date and the identifier as strings and return the corresponding code from the table. `testSheet` was just the name of my sheet. This will return a zero-length string if nothing is found.

On the line `Set r = ws.Range("$A:$Z")` just set the range to be large enough to encompass your entire lookup table.

```
Public Function FindCode(date_number, ident) As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("testSheet")
Set r = ws.Range("$A:$Z")

Set c = r.Find(date_number)

If Not c Is Nothing Then
    daterow = c.Row
End If

Set c = r.Find(ident)

If Not c Is Nothing Then
    identcol = c.Column
End If

If daterow = Empty Or identcol = Empty Then
    FindCode = ""
Else
    FindCode = ws.Cells(daterow, identcol)
End If

End Function
```

Example usage would be:

```
Debug.Print FindCode("20/04/2010", "ident2")
```